# How do I summon a mob with a custom loot_table? I don't understand how get a loot_table from a datapack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've gone around to various sites, nothing has helped me except for the minecraft wiki when it came to how to make a loot_table and how to structure a datapack.

This is what the path from the world folder to the `loot_tables` folder looks like.

```
-saves
---dungeonMap
-----datapacks
-------DungeonRunner (datapack name)
---------data
-----------KeyItems (namespace name)
-------------loot_tables
---------------StrongAxe.json (loot table file)
```

I tried doing `/summon pig ~ ~ ~ {DeathLootTable:"KeyItems:loot_tables/StrongAxe.json"}`. It summons the pig, but it doesn't drop anything. (This is in 1.13.2)

This is what is in the loot_table:
https://pastebin.com/XjQath97

Comment: What error are you seeing?  We can't read your mind, so more useful details are always better.

Comment: It doesn't return an error because nbt format is correct and it still summons the pig. The pigs just never drops the item.

Comment: That is an important piece of information that should be added to your question.

Comment: Does that loot table work if you replace one of the default loot tables with it?

Comment: @FabianRöling https://pastebin.com/zpaGtCkH Does this look right. Cause I tried this and when I spawn a pig with a spawn egg and then kill it. It just drops pork.

Comment: Is the data pack enabled?

Comment: @FabianRöling Yes it is enabled

Answer (score 2):

**I found the problem!**

The names of any folder and file that are inside of the custom datapack folder **MUST NOT** have any uppercase characters. The custom datapack folder may have uppercase characters.

Comment: That's interesting.  I would have assumed that you just had to match the case of the filenames with what you have in Minecraft.